# Enviar formulario post a un controlador y regresar los datos obtenidos a mi pagina inicial

Tags: javascript, post

Hola amigos estoy haciendo un código para mostrar marcadores en un **google map** para ello seguí este tutorial: [aqui](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/probleme-avec-php-bdd-js-xml-api-google)

El código esta muy bueno cuando haces un simple `select` a tu **BD** eso muestra todos los marcadores registrados, pero yo necesito extraer los marcadores según usuario y fecha.

Entonces adapte el código de la siguiente forma como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo dos archivos **mapa.php** y **mapa.controlador.php** desde **mapa.php** envió por medio de un formulario utilizando `POST` al nombre y la fecha, esto hará que en mi controlador me dé un formulario con todos los puntos devolviendo en un archivo `xml`. entonces en mi **mapa.php** hay una función llamada **initMap** que consulta ese formulario y debería mostrarme en un mapa todos los puntos.

Entonces mi duda es como hacer para enviar por `POST` al nombre y la fecha y este sin abrirse en otra pagina me devuelva los datos para que puedan ser leídos en mi mismo archivo osea **mapa.php**.

Hice un formulario pero este me abre mi controlador en otra pagina y no me lleva los datos a mi pagina inicial para mostrarlo en el mapa.

```
<form method='POST' action='../controlador/mapa.controlador.php' id='myform' name="myform" target="request">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Código</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtcodigousuario" name="txtcodigousuario" readonly="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Usuario (Digite las iniciales de los nombres del usuario)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtnombres" name="txtnombres" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Telefono</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtMovil" name="txtMovil" readonly="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Fecha de Evento</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtfechevent" name="txtfechevent" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" >
</form>
```

También dejo la función que se encuentra en mi **mapa.php** que debería extraer los datos de mi controlador después de enviarse por `post` el nombre y la fecha:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.8153983,-79.8351688),
    zoom: 12.0
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  downloadUrl('../controlador/mapa.controlador.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marcadores');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('movil');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');
      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });

      var text = document.createElement('br');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = type
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    });
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
    callback(request, request.status);
  }
};
```

Agradezco mucha toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola buenas, creo que entiendo lo que quieres. Has pensado usar AJAX? te permite hacer consultas y recibir respuestas del servidor sin que se recarge la pagina. P.D.: ajax de jquery es bastante fácil de usar

Comment: Efectivamente Ivan lo solucione usando AJAX

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionase :)